# Should I list on my resume my entrepreneurial project as freelance or own

Tags: resume, job-search, work-experience, startup

I read that listing your side projects on your resume is a good idea. I'm currently working on an e-commerce project (I am a software engineer) since 2 years ago. It's a big project with a lot going on, but at the same time I need to keep being employee until I can make money with it. Yes I'm very busy programming almost 24/7.

So, I would like to list it on my resume but I am not sure if the potential employers will think that I won't be 100% committed with the company or that I can leave them anytime soon (which hopefully sooner than later I can). 
I was thinking to list it maybe as freelance work that I am doing for someone else. 
What do you think?

Answer (score 2):

I would just list it as a side project. Downplay how big it is and make it seem more like a hobby project than something you would leave your job for. It would have to be a pretty kick-ass app for it to make as much as you do full-time, and while I am not doubting your ability to do it, most employers probably will. I wouldn't be worried.

Answer (score 2):

1. Side projects are interesting to an employer to the extent that they can see the relevance of what you are doing to their situation.
2. If your projects are relevant, interesting and have money making potential, there is a possibility that some aggressive employer claims what you are doing as their own.

You just are going to have to weigh your own risks and decide for yourself what risks are worthwhile to you.